# Why looping via shapes in Excel VBA gives 1004 error?

Tags: excel, vba, controls, shapes

I have written the following procedure that is run by clicking customized icon on customized tab.

The procedure is supposed to:

- find row and column of a cell that is the (TopLeft) closest to the shape
- set row height of the found cell to be 10 units greater than shape height

The code is the following:

```vb
Sub AdjustRowHeightToCode(control As IRibbonControl)
'Sub AdjustRowHeightToCode()
'A procedure that sets height of a merged cell in which shape is located
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim col_n As Long
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim sh_cell As Range
        
    Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Wyniki")
        
    For Each sh In wsh.Shapes
        Set sh_cell = sh.TopLeftCell
        col_n = sh_cell.Column

        If col_n >= 2 And col_n <= 5 Then
        'We want to set height of cells from columns B to E
            sh.Select
            sh_cell.RowHeight = sh.Height + 10
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

When I run the procedure by clicking icon, I get

**Run-time error '1004':
Aplication-defined or object-defined error**

The debugger in the `For` loop stops and seems not to detect `sh.TopLeftCell' property as can be seen on the screen below.

On the contrary, it is able to detect **`Colum` and even `Row` properties of `sh_cell`**.
[image]

I still do not understand why the debugger stops at this point?
Do you have any clue?

Comment: I fail to understand why you do `row = sh.TopLeftCell.row`, `col = sh.TopLeftCell.Column`, `Set cell = wsh.Cells(row, col)` and `sh.Select` when you could just do `Set cell = sh.TopLeftCell` and not select the shape. Anyway have you added a watch to control the variables?

Comment: Don't use `row` as a variable name. It's an object itself in VBA. Try something like `nrow` and try again your code. Notice how `sh.TopLeftCell.row` got the `row` part lowercases when it should be with capital R like `TopLeftCell.Row`. VBA is confused b this and it's using your empty variable as an object in `TopLeftCell`. Notice how `TopLeftCell.Column` works properly but if you do `Dim column as Variant` it won't work (and the C would not be capital)

Comment: ... To get `row` capitalized again, you need to declare it with `Dim Row As Long`. Now you csn rename it.

Comment: @Atmo, you are right that there is no use in `row` and `col` variables.
Thank you all for your answers. 
My problem is that there are cases when the procedure works fine and does not produce the error :(

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns VBA is not confused, [Intellisence is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606203/len-keyboard-not-colored-as-a-keyword-in-vbe?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment128255770_72606203). This has no effect on the execution of the code. It would be impossible for VBA to use a user level variable instead a property on an object, that doesn't happen. There is nothing wrong with declaring a variable named `row`.

Comment: @GSerg, so what is wrong with the code now in new version? Why does it still produce the same error?

Comment: @JohnSnow I have no idea, it doesn't happen to me. It happens to you, so debug it! What is `sh` when it happens? Have you tried adding that `sh` to the Watch window? Does it even have a `TopLeftCell`? What do its other properties return?

Comment: @GSerg,
As for now I can not replicate the error as It works fine. But it happened a few times for me that it was OK during tests and there was a moment when the error occurred so I can not tell you now what are the properties of `sh` object.

Anyway, thanks for your hints. If the problem occurs one more time I will try to debug it properly and I will come back with the new observations.

Comment: @GSerg, I have added a new description with new screen above. For now, I used `On error resume Next` statement but to be honest I completely do not understand the problem.